# Vuejs v-bind class not applying the classes dynamically

Tags: vue.js

```
<button @click="startEffect"> Start Effect</button>
<br/>
<div id="effect" class="highlight" :class="{highlight: enableHighlight}"></div>
```

I just need the highlight class to be applied based on the data property `enableHighlight` but for some reason It doesn't apply the class when the `startEffect` function is called.

```
<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                enableHighlight: false
            }
        },
        methods: {
            startEffect: function () {
                this.enableHighlight = !this.enableHighlight;
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

I have debugged and confirmed that value of `enableHighlight` is switched when clicking the button and that the CSS classes are present. However upon clicking the button the class is not applied to the div.

Comment: Why do you have `class="highlight"`?

Comment: @JamesCoyle I tried removing that it doesn't make a difference

Comment: Can you add a snippet that shows the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really mess with `Vue` when having a "normal" `class` attribute and one dynamic. Remove the normal one.
`<div id="effect" :class="{highlight: enableHighlight}"></div>`

To make it work, you need to remove the `function` in `startEffect`'s definition:

```
startEffect() {
    this.enableHighlight = !this.enableHighlight;
}
```

Why? because `this` isn't the same in the different ways to define the function. Learn more about `this` [here](https://javascript.info/object-methods).